# Geoserver SLD text symbology

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I have problem with the Geoserver.

I have a layer (called "cities") which contains points with attributes.
(*ID, Name, Layer, etc....*)
I'd like to write out all the names (at now it doesn't matter if overlap eachother).
In the geoserver the points showed correctly but the text-s are missing. Under an exact zoom level the all text shown correctly but above that level nothing. Just the marker point.

This is my SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Point with styled label</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>GeoServer SLD Cook Book: Point with styled label</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
        <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
           <ogc:PropertyName>layer</ogc:PropertyName><![CDATA[
]]>
           <ogc:Literal>17</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>textstring</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <VendorOption name="spaceAround">-10</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">1</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Is there any basic restrictions to the labels or any default settings?
Thanks! :)

---

**Update:**
I updated the SLD with the "conflitresolution".
In the attached image you can see, nothing happened.
Originaly the basic map created in Arcgis. The cartographer who originaly (a few years ago) created the map placed every single label to the right place (that time they made paper maps not webmaps). Now I'd like to put almost every label back to their place. The original shape has different layer to bigger and smaller cities and exact anchor point, angle, font size ect....
So that is why I'd like to show all label at the same time and scale, because the layera are scale dependent.
[image]

Thanks again :)

---

**Update 2:**
I tired Mario's code but still the same problem :/
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I guess your map is tiled, and GeoServer by default won't paint partial labels, those crossing tile boundaries, as there is no guarantee the other half will be visible. You can force them to appear like this:

```
 <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
 <VendorOption name="partials">true</VendorOption>
```

You will need at least version 2.6.x, see also http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#partials

Comment: I am use this VendorOption, but not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default GeoServer tries very hard to not overlap your labels (as this generally what the user wants). You can change this behaviour by setting the vendor option [conflictResoloution](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#conflictresolution) to false.

```
<VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
```

Comment: i tried but still nothing. (see original question for more details). Thanks :)

Comment: you will need to remove the other vendor options.

Comment: still nothing change :/

Answer (score 0):

I often have the same problem and I mostly solve it with following vendor options

```
      <VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">0.1</VendorOption>
      <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
      <VendorOption name="spaceAround">-1</VendorOption>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thank you your answer. I tired the code and you can see above the result. The labels now overlap each other but still have some wich are don't seen. Tahnk you again! Gergo

Comment: Yes I know, but this is the best I found. If you find better solution, please let me know. :)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try a smaller value for:

```
<VendorOption name="spaceAround">-10</VendorOption>
```